# Is there a way to easily combine Secure-Spreadsheet with Laravel-Excel for exports? (Or getting the binary data from Laravel-Excel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, laravel-10

I'm currently using Laravel-Excel to export Excel files: https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel

I also used in testing nick322/secure-spreadsheet: https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet and it does password-protect the Excel files as I wanted.

But now I need to combine between the two. Is there a way to easily combine the two? I'm currently exporting Excel using the `Excel::download` method of Laravel-Excel:

```
return Excel::download(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
```

Using this method, it immediately creates and downloads the file so I can't use the secure-spreadsheet on it.

I can however store it first:

```
return Excel::store(new InvoicesExport, 'invoices.xlsx');
```

And then run the secure script on it, then download the secured Excel file, and delete both files.

But is there something simpler to do?

the secure-spreadsheet packages does accept binary data as input, however Laravel-Excel only returns a `BinaryFileResponse`, not just the binary data: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/#download-the-file

So I can't get the binary data before it downloads it.

Maybe then I can somehow get the raw binary data before it turns into a response? Or any other way?